# What substances are absorbed through skin when pores are open through heat?

Tags: dermatology, toxicity, chemical, heat, pores

It can go directly in your bloodstream. Most substances are absorbed faster through skin than when ingested(from what I've read)
I know apparently Chloride is effectively and quickly absorbed.

> "Surfactants like sodium lauryl-sulfate increase the skin penetration of water-soluble substances, possibly by increasing the skin permeability of water." --------Source; from wikipedia; (Baggot JD. Disposition and Fate of Drugs in the Body. Chapter 5 in Veterinary Pharmacology and Therapeutics, 6th edition, 1988 Iowa State Press, Ames.)

More about Lauryl and other absorption factors in very complete study here
 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3283952/

"It has been reported that anionic surfactants like sodium lauryl sulfate can penetrate and interact with the skin, producing large alterations in the barrier properties.[30] An additional mechanism for the penetration enhancement by SLS involves the hydrophobic interaction of the SLS alkyl chain with the skin structure which leaves the end sulfate group of the surfactant exposed, creating additional sites in the membrane. This results in the development of repulsive forces that separate the protein matrix, uncoil the filaments, and expose more water binding sites, hence increasing the hydration level of skin.[12]  "

That is a very serious health concern since it's in alot of shampoo and soaps, there is also alot of variation of Lauryl-sulfate based/similar substances.

What other substances would increase skin absorption?
A few from the study above ;

> "There are a variety of substances which have been identified as
>   absorption enhancers, such as alcohols, azones and derivatives,
>   non-polar compounds, ureia and cyclic derivatives, pyrrolidones and
>   derivatives, cyclodextrins, aprotic solvents, surfactants, and even
>   electrophoresis, electroporation and physical ultrasound.  "

- Glycols
- Acids and fatty alcohols

Comment: How is that a very serious health concern?  Good stuff and bad stuff can be absorbed.

Comment: Because it can transport other poisons more effectively through the skin, and it's a poison by itself. Which goes directly to the blood stream,and may end up in different places,namely the liver.

It's not the kind of substance you would use to absorb any "good stuff" for those reasons.

Comment: Never absorb  good stuff?   Patches are used for a variety of medicine.

Comment: It was obvious and clearly mentionned,that I was talking about Sodium Lauryl Sulfates (and similar substances) . And not at all about the potential beneficial use of the skin absorption effect of medicines.

Comment: Not clear to me.

Comment: A problem here is that you are asking for list and already give us a list. I understand your concern (I think). But this has to be narrowed down.